# having trouble in transforming a array in php

Tags: php, laravel

i have this array

```
[ 
    [[222] => 1 [333] => 2 [444] => 0],
    [[222] => 0 [333] => 2 [444] => 1],
    [[222] => 1 [333] => 2 [444] => 0]
]
```

where [222], [333], [444] are student ids
and 0 means absent
    1 means Present
    2 means Leave

i want the output will

```
[ 'student_id' => '222'
  'present' => 2 /* total present*/
  'absent' => 1  /* total absent*/
  'leave'  => 0 /* total leave*/
],
[ 'student_id' => '333'
  'present' => 0 /* total present*/
  'absent' => 0  /* total absent*/
  'leave'  => 3 /* total leave*/
],
```

etc.

please give me some soluation in php code

Comment: What have you tried so far to resolve this issue?

Comment: I have no idea how can I achieve this problem

Comment: Are you using laravel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does exactly what you want, but this site is not a coding service, so i really think you should take the time to understand how i did, and next time try something and share it on your post:

```
$array = [
    [
        "222" => 1, 
        "333" => 2,
        "444" => 0
    ],
    [
        "222" => 0, 
        "333" => 2,
        "444" => 1
    ],
    [
        "222" => 1, 
        "333" => 2,
        "444" => 0
    ]
];
$results = [];
foreach($array as $k=>$v){
    foreach($v as $id=>$value){
        if(!isset($results[$id])){
            $results[$id] = [
                'student_id' => $id,
                'present' => 0,
                'absent' => 0,  
                'leave'  => 0
            ];
        }
        if($value == 0){
            $results[$id]['absent']++;
        }
        if($value == 1){
            $results[$id]['present']++;
        }
        if($value == 2){
            $results[$id]['leave']++;
        }
    }
}
$results = array_values($results);
print_r($results);
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like `JSON` value with there respective keys. You may do that firstly you can arrange these values in PHP ARRAY using `foreach` then convert that array in JSON.

`foreach` looping is the best way to access each key/value pair from an array.

`foreach($featured as $key => $value){...}`

The `$key => $value` in the foreach loop refers to the key-value pairs in associative arrays, where the key serves as the index to determine the value instead of a number like 0,1,2,... In PHP, associative arrays look like this

`$featured = array('student_id' => '111', 'present' => '2', etc.);`